# Edge smoothing/correction after removing colour background

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, .net-core

I've written some code that removes a colour from an image such as a person in front of a green screen. I do this with Kaliko.ImageLibrary using the chroma key filter.

This works fine, no matter what tolerances I try, I am always left with a jagged edge of about 1px tracing around the image that still has the colour that we removed (I understand why that happens).

Is there a recommended method to post process the image after the chroma key to remove that edge and smooth it? Or should I preprocess it with a filter, create a mask and clip the original image to it?

Sorry I am new to image processing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm fairly sure "Is there a recommended method" kind of questions are deemed off-topic according to SO rules. This is a question on how to _solve_ a graphics problem, rather than a question on how to _program_ that solution.

Comment: I'm specifically asking how one would achieve the result, using C# on .net core.

Comment: And that's not a programming issue. It's a graphics handling issue. First figure out how to do it manually if you were to use something like Photoshop, then try to automate that process. I suggest you look up some tutorials on how to do digital greenscreening.

Comment: Indeed I have done. I have got so far as it is almost perfect. I just want to know if anyone has a routine or library they have used to anti alias the edges of an image at least.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem **and what has been done so far to solve it.**" Your question is the edges handling, not the greenscreening as a whole, and as far as I can see, you came and asked about it here _instead_ of trying to solve it.

Comment: Yeah yeah, close the q.